# Logging of processes and changes

Tags: php, laravel, logging, api-design

Hello everybody I want to raise maybe a little discussion question:

I am creating currently an application which consists of small "bots" who are connected to cnc server.

The server application is created in Php/Laravel8 with it's own api.

The Bots are written/will be in Python.

I want to log every action/connection of the bots and the server. Also I want to show the latest actions to the user in his/her dashboard and down the road in the bot-details.

I could now create 2 tables:

```sql
   log_types
   bot_logs
```

And log every interaction of the bots with the api and store it into the database.
This has, for me 2 major downsides:

- More load on the mysql server
- php artisan migrate:fresh will delete everything

On the other hand I could use the logging system, provided by laravel. The Channel in this case would be then a log document on the server. The downside is here for me, that reading and writing logs is slower, than writing in a database,  I guess at least.

For the moment my attempt is, that I will use for the server logging (major logging) the logging engine of laravel and for all bot-activities/api-interactions I use the database.

What do you think about this approach?
I postponed the implementation of it, because for the development I use telescope, but I need to figure out a good wow until I will have a productive solution.

Kind regards and thank you for your thoughts.

Comment: Don't design your system around assumptions about performance issues you don't have. Either build the feature you need and address performance issues as they arise, or test your assumptions and base your design on the results.

Comment: Little misconception. `php artisan migrate:fresh` should only delete everything in your default database connection. If you were to use a different connection for the logs, or replicate/copy it periodically that shouldn't be an issue. Reading and Writing to a text file should be faster, as long as you don't need to do complicated things with the logs files after (filtering, grouping values and so on). You could also use redis. It really depends on how complex your logs are going to get.

Comment: I haven't got the purpose of redis until now? Do you have a good explaination about it? @AlexHowansky I get what you say, but instead of making the same error like dozens of others I want to try to learn from the experience of others :-)

Comment: I've given you the experience of others. Don't look for micro-optimization solutions to a problem you're not actually experiencing. Just build what you need.

Comment: And why is "migrate:fresh deletes everything" a downside? How often do you plan on running it in your production environment?

Comment: @Alex this is really a good point